# Reading a large json file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large JSONL file (~100 GB). I want to convert this to a pandas dataframe and apply some functions on a column by iterating over all the rows .

Whats the best way to read this JSONL file ? I am doing the following currently but that gets stuck (running this on GCP)

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data = []
with open("my_jsonl_file", 'r') as file:
      for line in file:
          data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smaller data you can simply use:

```
import pandas as pd
path = "test.jsonl"
data = pd.read_json(path, lines=True)
```

For large data, you can use something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1'])
import jsonlines
data = jsonlines.open(path)

for line in data.iter():
  # get data in line
  df.append({'c1': data})
```